# Дана символьная строка.Вывести на экран те символы, которые встречаются в ней более трех раз, для каждого из символов указать количество повторений

Tags: python

```
word = input('Введите слово: ')
while word:
    if word.count(word[0])>3: 
        print(word[0], ':', word.count(word[0]))
    word = word.replace(word[0], '')
```

Есть ли возможность не использовать методы count(), replace()?(Не использовать массив(список) и более сложные структуры. Используются только операции со строками.

Comment: сделайте словарь со счетчиком, в цикле увеличивайте соответствующий счетчик на единицу. а потом отберите нужные

Comment: Если не использовать словари и массивы (в этом случае - тот же словарь), то делаете два вложенных цикла, в каждом подсчитываете количество текущего символа и если он больше 3 - сразу выводите на экран. При подсчете меняете символ на какую-нибудь константу. Но со словарем будет быстрее - один проход по строке и один проход по словарю. По сути вам нужно написать замену функции `count()`

Comment: вообщето, строка - это список символов. если совсем без списков, то  даже инпут надо выкинуть

Comment: @splash58 Ну нет, строка, конечно, индексируется и итерируется, но это не список ))  То есть с ней можно до какой-то степени обращаться так же как и со списком, но это не значит, что строка - это список )

Comment: @CrazyElf кстати, интересный вопрос, будет время, покопаюсь  - после появления разнодлинных символов в utf-8, я даже не знаю, как реализуется физически строка символов, чтоб обеспечить индексный доступ. раньше было просто - байт на символ, там такой классический массив

Comment: @splash58 Ну, надо смотреть исходники. Они наверняка на `C++`. А он тоже наверное с `UTF` строками как-то должен же уметь работать нативно. Интересно, да.

Comment: @splash58 я предполагаю, что внутри в виде UTF-32 хранится, тогда возможно просто массив из 32-битных чисел.

Comment: @insolor очень разумное предположение

Answer (score 0):

Можно с помощью `Counter`:

```py
from collections import Counter

word = input('Введите слово: ')

c = Counter(word)

for letter in c:
    if c[letter] > 3:
        print(f"{letter} : {c[letter]}")
```

Comment: Если в задании прямо написано "Не использовать массив(список) и более сложные структуры", то думаете `Counter` значит можно? ))

Answer (score 0):

Такой код выполнят поставленную задачу, используя только числа и строки:

```py
word = input("Введите слово: ")


def count(string: str, letter: str) -> int:  # (1)
    result = 0
    for l in string:
        if l == letter:
            result += 1
    return result


checked = ""  # (2)
for letter in word:
    if letter not in checked:
        occurrences_number = count(word, letter)
        if occurrences_number > 3:
            print(f"{letter} : {occurrences_number}")
        checked += letter
```

Описание кода:

1. Определяем свой `count`.
2. В строке `checked` храним уже проверенные символы.